# commerce kickstart adding regions and render page

Tags: theming, commerce

After installing commerce kickstart my base theme is Commerce Kickstart Theme 7.x-2.10 . I need to add a new region before "content" region. In my "commerce_kickstart_theme.info" file i added my region name as

regions[contentfull] = Contentfull.

In blocks i am able to see my region. But where to render/print the page. In which file in need to render/print. And which css i have to edit